# Why is Bash not evaluating the executable bit correctly in Alpine 3.14.2?

Tags: bash, test, alpine-linux

In a dockerized Alpine 3.14.2 running Bash 5.1.4(1), I encountered a strange behaviour in a Bash script. The essential line is a test for executability of a file, which always fails. This is the if test in a nutshell:

```bash
bash-5.1# if [ ! -x /opt/java/openjdk/bin/java ]; then echo "something strange just happened"; fi
something strange just happened
```

But, the numerous ways I know of to "test" executability all show a different result:

```bash
bash-5.1# ls -la /opt/java/openjdk/bin/java
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         12648 Jan 21  2021 /opt/java/openjdk/bin/java
bash-5.1# stat -c "%A" /opt/java/openjdk/bin/java
-rwxr-xr-x
bash-5.1# /opt/java/openjdk/bin/java --version
openjdk 15.0.2 2021-01-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 15.0.2+7)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 15.0.2+7, mixed mode, sharing)
```

In order to get my script working, the executability test inside Bash should return the proper result. **But why doesn't it?**

There is a rather long list of things I checked or tried out, some of them after suggestions from the community:

- The check fails all (tested) executables. Even Bash itself. The result is always wrong:

```bash
bash-5.1# if [ ! -x /bin/bash ]; then echo "this is weird"; fi
this is weird
```

- @KamilMaciorowski suggested to test for bash overrides in his comment. But the output seems fine:

```bash
bash-5.1# type -a [
[ is a shell builtin
```

- This is a strace on the command (thanks @zevzek):

```bash
bash-5.1# strace -fe trace=access,faccessat,stat bash -c '[ -x /bin/bash ]'
stat("/root", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0700, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat(".", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0700, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/root", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0700, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/root", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0700, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat(".", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0700, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/local/sbin/bash", 0x7ffc257ec050) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/local/bin/bash", 0x7ffc257ec050) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/sbin/bash", 0x7ffc257ec050)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/bin/bash", 0x7ffc257ec050)   = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/sbin/bash", 0x7ffc257ec050)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/bin/bash", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=760136, ...}) = 0
stat("/bin/bash", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=760136, ...}) = 0
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

- Using the "real" `[` from Busybox works fine, but not using `[` in Bash. But I can't possibly rewrite all Bash scripts shipped with software in that container:

```bash
bash-5.1# which [
/usr/bin/[
bash-5.1# if [ ! -x /bin/bash ]; then echo "this is weird"; fi
this is weird
bash-5.1# if /usr/bin/[ ! -x /bin/bash ]; then echo "this is weird"; fi
bash-5.1#
```

- The filesystem is not mounted "noexec" (only the ones you would expect, like /proc)
- Other tests like `[ -f /bin/bash ]` or `[ -f /tmp/not_there ]` are correct, only `-x` seems broken
- I tried Bash 5.1.1 and it worked there. I then went through the [Bash release notes](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-5.1-patches/), but I can't find anything relevant in between.

Comment: Could not reproduce on  `adoptopenjdk/openjdk15-openj9:x86_64-alpine-jre-15.0.2_7_openj9-0.24.0` (`1a455cef4162`) after `apk add bash`.

Comment: @gendergap Indeed, when asked for clarifications, please _don't_ place them in the comment section but edit the question instead, so that any contributor has all relevant informations immediately at a glance. Reading through the comment section on the other hand is cumbersome, and comments are subject to removal by moderators without notice.

Comment: Is the filesystem mounted `noexec` by any chance?

Answer (score 7):

It seems as though Alpine 3.14 is pertinent to a known bug here. All the technical details are part of an already [open issue there](https://github.com/alpinelinux/docker-alpine/issues/156) (which I initially did not find because I was always looking for the "executable" bit).

The short answer is to not use Bash in Alpine 3.14 for the time being.

The long answer would be to update the specific set of affected components, which in a Docker context is impractical most of the time.

Comment: "This is related to faccessat2 syscall has been enabled in musl in alpine starting 3.14. Due to a bug in runc it fails if your kernel do not support faccessat2." -- oopsie! Yep, that would cause some chaos. Also might explain why the strace doesn't show the call to `faccessat()`...

Comment: That part is way beyond my knowledge! But yes, it seems you were on the right track there. Kudos!

Comment: not really, just on a track that looked similar. I was thinking about it being a bug, though, but had no clue at all as to what could cause a bug like that...

Comment: BTW, it looks like this question and answer pair is your first contribution to the site. Quite successful debut. Way to go!